# Why two subprocesses created by Java behave differently?

Tags: java, c++, jvm, persistence, subprocess

I use Java `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command)` to create a subprocess and print its `pid` as follows:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

Process p2;
try {       
    p2 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
    Field f2 = p2.getClass().getDeclaredField("pid");
    f2.setAccessible(true);
    System.out.println( f2.get( p2 ) );
} catch (Exception ie)
{
    System.out.println("Yikes, you are not supposed to be here");
}

}
```

I tried both C++ executable and Java executable (.jar file). Both executables will continuously print out "Hello World" to stdout.

When `cmd` is the C++ executable, the `pid` is printed out to console but the subprocess gets killed as soon as `main()` returns. However, when I call the .jar executable in `cmd`, the subprocess does not get killed, which is the desired behavior.

I don't understand why same Java code, with different executables can behave so differently. How should I modify my code so that I could have persistent subprocesses in Java?

PS: I am using Ubuntu 9.10 and OpenJDK-1.6. (Not sure if they matters~)

Newbie in this field. Any suggestion is welcomed.

Lily

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The C++ EXE is almost certainly marked as a console app.  I'm thinking a jar would be considered a GUI app by default, and would do the standard detach-from-the-main-process thing.

If you were to take the C++ code and turn it into a GUI app, i think you'd see it behave similarly to the jar.

Comment: That's not quite the answer the OP is expecting, I assume. How do you easily "take the C++ code and turn it into a GUI app"?

Comment: Easy answer?  You don't.  Console and Windows subsystems are separate, and used differently.  A Windows app isn't going to get a console, so unless you're attaching to the process, you'll never see the output.

Comment: Not-so-easy answer: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682055(v=VS.85).aspx

Comment: thanks for your reply. But the thing is: I don't care the console output. As long as the subprocess is still running after the main() returns, I am already happy~